# How to fix session error in magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, session

How to fix error "Your session has expired"

[image]

Comment: this problem remains in my case. the website is running not on localhost.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158018)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158018)

Answer (score 3):

1. Change your **`Baseurl`** and **`Baseurl secure`** to **`127.0.0.1`** instead of **`localhost`**
2. Then run **`cache:flush`**
3. Or delete all directories below  **`var/cache`**

Answer (score 1):

I've searched for an answer to this error that just showed up on our production Magento 2 (2.3.4-p2) site today.  Every single one says the same thing, go here in core_config_data and change localhost to 127.0.0.1, but at least in 2.3.4, the record in that table with the base_url values does not have localhost, so there's nothing to change.

I don't know if an earlier version of 2.3 had these values in core_config_data, but they exist nowhere in 2.3.4-p2.  I also flushed the cache at the command line, deleted all the directories under var/cache, but still the error continued.

I found through trial and error that clearing the cache in my web browser fixed the problem.

Just pointing out that this exact error may come up not because of the server, but because of your web browser, for whatever reason.  It happened to me in the middle of troubleshooting a completely different problem.  I signed out and tried to sign back in, but that also gave a similar error -- even though I was fine 3 hours earlier.

The only thing that happened in those 3 hours was I came back to test the same problem I was working on before and was stopped by this error.  So, I didn't change anything on the server to start the problem, it just happened on my FireFox web browser, which I only use to work on Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost for that execute below query.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'https://127.0.0.1/magento/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

then clear cache by the cli command

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too
I converted 127.0.0.1 to http://new.mys.com for ease of use in the httpd-vhost file
That's why my site on Localhost didn't work properly

If you have converted 127.0.0.1 to a domain in Windows, delete it

The error happens because Windows can’t translate the localhost or youre domain URL to 127.0.0.1 in core_config_data table, thus the add to cart function does not work properly

As described above, the best solution for this issue is to set web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to IP address 127.0.0.1.

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/yourwebsite/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://127.0.0.1/yourwebsite/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Finally, clean cache

`php bin/magento cache:clean`